# How do I use Node.js in a website to run an .EXE file?

Tags: node.js, server, exe

```
         export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request,response) => {
          console.log("fun() start");
          exec('Notepad.exe', function(err, data) {  
           console.log(err)
               console.log(data.toString());                       

               });
```

I have tried this code to run .exe file on my server but it is displaying

Error: could not handle the request on my webpage.

Please help me.

Comment: `var exec = require('child_process').execFile;` hope you have this..
And can you please add the error you are seeing?

Comment: @SunilBN I have already added that.